# Is it possible to use Karate UI test on remote webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, karate, browserstack

Actually i am looking to integrate browserstack with Karate for UI automation.
If its possible or anyone tried then let me know the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the `webDriverSession` in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#webdriversession

Example:

```
* def session = { capabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' }, desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } }
* configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', webDriverSession: '#(session)', start: false, webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:9515/wd/hub' }
```

Comment: Do i need to add this in feature file?
If yes then how to call it in .java file?

Comment: @BhanuAgarwal yes please read the docs. there is also an advanced example here using AWS DeviceFarm: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-devicefarm-demo

Comment: Still not getting how to add above one in java. Above one is json and i am looking like adding capabilities in .java file

Comment: @BhanuAgarwal I give up. maybe someone else can help you, all the best

Comment: I added capabilities in map but not getting idea where to add this map. Even its doing handshake as well with browserstack (connection getting established).

Comment: @BhanuAgarwal best of luck. you need it :)